# Monthly and daily insights on the same page in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am working on a report which is expected to provide both daily and monthly insights on the same page. I have set a page level filter
on the current date.So all my visuals are filtered for current date when the report is loaded. Now I need to show some trends like new accounts created
1 month prior to current date.

What I am trying to achieve here is , I want all my card visuals to reflect values for the current date say 14/06/2019 (which I have set as page filter). 
For the graphs I want to show trend over the past month.If my date is 14/06/2019, I should see values from 13-May-2019 untill 13-Jun-2019.

Tried this but it just shows 1 value for 14/06/2019.

```
New Accounts 1M =
CALCULATE (
    [New accounts],
    DATESINPERIOD ( DateTable[Date], TODAY (), -1, MONTH ),
    ALL ( DateTable[Date] )
)
```

Also tried, gives same result as above.

```
New Accounts 1M =
CALCULATE ( [New accounts], DATEADD ( DateTable[Date], -1, MONTH ) )
```

Is there a way to get this working ?

Comment: Why don't you just remove your page level filter and use visual level filters instead?

Comment: I removed the page level filter, so now there are no filters. So now what I need is a DAX formula which calculates the No of Accounts created in the last 1 month, which I would like to show as a line graph with values for each day. I tried the below but it gets me values for all months in the Accounts table starting from Jan 2018, where as what I am looking to get is just values for past 30 days from current date. CALCULATE([New accounts],DATEADD(DateTable[Date],-30,DAY))

Comment: The relative date slicer was exactly what I wanted.https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-may-feature-summary/#relativeDateSlicer.